# I want to use same UserInterface with different Data in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I have `25 tabs` in a `UITabBarController` and each tab display a `tableview` with different data. Can I  use the same `tableview` with different data in all the tabs. 4 tabs display at bottom remaining will display in more.

P.S. : I am coding in swift.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can. Just instantiate a new instance of your view controller, hook it up to a data source and delegate, and present it.

25 tabs in a tab bar controller is insane. You need to rethink your user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You can use switch to detect selected tabbar item index and there you can assign your data source as per your requirement.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        //suppose index is your tab Bar item index
        switch index {
        case 0:
           return YOUR_DATA_ARRAY1.count
        case 1:
            return YOUR_DATA_ARRAY2.count
            .
            .
            .
        case 25:
            return YOUR_DATA_ARRAY25.count
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        //You can use same switch here to access objects from your data array and use it to assign values for cell
        return cell;
    }
```

**SIDE NOTE** : Actually your approach is wrong, as your data is very large. You can still use this approach but I will highly recommend to rethink over it.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. My suggestion will be to create a base ViewController with a tableView and extend each of your ViewControllers connected to your tabs. Then all the connected view controller should just change the data array according to its need.

SO, lets say, you have a base ViewController name `BaseViewController.swift`. In that controller you have an array named dataSource like-

```
var dataSource = [String]()
```

Then add the required delegates and datasource in the protocol list, like-

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

now add your tableview right after that.

```
 var myTableView: UITableView!
```

Now in the viewDidLoad method, add your table.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myTableView = UITableView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.myTableView.delegate! = self
        self.myTableView.dataSource! = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.myTableView)
    }
```

Now just implement the datasource methods.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
    return self.dataSource.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel.text = self.dataSource[indexPath.row] //assuming you only have a string in your array
        return cell;
}
```

Now all you need to do is extend this class. Let's say, your first Tab is corresponding with ViewControllerA.swift.

So, just extend like this-

```
class ViewControllerA: BaseViewController
```

and then in the `viewDidLoad` method, assign your data array as the `dataSource` array.

So, let's say, the 1st controller will show an array name dataA.

So, you just do this in your `viewDidLoad` method,

```
self.dataSource = dataA
```

In case your dataSource needs to show complex data like a class object with image, title or multiple labels, you can just override the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in that particular class. That way, it would affect other controllers.

Hope this helps.